# I need some help getting dark mode operating correctly with Nuxt3, pinia, and tailwindcss

Tags: vuejs3, tailwind-css, pinia, nuxt3

I am trying to get a dark mode toggle working with tailwindcss and nuxt3. I have it somewhat working. By that I mean it does what I want it to do but when I reload the browser (while I have dark mode enabled) I get the error below and the dark mode button will quickly flicker to the light mode button. This also happens in the opposite direction where if I reload the browser while on light mode the dark mode button will flicker quickly. The dark mode / light mode toggles do what is intended i.e. changes the background color. How can I fix this?

```
chunk-3Q27KRJ5.js:97 [Vue warn]: Hydration text content mismatch in <i>:
- Client: light_mode
- Server: dark_mode 
  at <Default > 
  at <LayoutLoader key="default" name="default" hasTransition=false > 
  at <NuxtLayout> 
  at <App key=3 > 
  at <NuxtRoot>
```

Below are default layout I am trying to get this working in, the pinia store and the buttons (which also live in default.vue)

Default.vue:

```
<script>
    import { useDarkThemeStore } from "@/stores/darkThemeStore";
    const toggleDarkMode = useDarkThemeStore();
    
    if (toggleDarkMode.themeIsDark === undefined){
        if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined'){
            if (localStorage.theme === 'dark'){
                toggleDarkMode.themeIsDark = true
                document.documentElement.classList.add('dark')
            } else{
                toggleDarkMode.themeIsDark = false
                document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark')
            }
            console.log(localStorage.theme)
        }
    }

    export default {
    data() {
        return {
            themeIsDark: toggleDarkMode.themeIsDark,
        };
    },
    methods: {
        changeTheme() {
            toggleDarkMode.switchTheme();
            this.themeIsDark = toggleDarkMode.themeIsDark;
            if (this.themeIsDark === true) {
                localStorage.theme = "dark";
                document.documentElement.classList.add("dark");
            } else {
                localStorage.theme = "light";
                document.documentElement.classList.remove("dark");
            }
        },
    },
    };
</script>
```

darkThemeStore.js

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useDarkThemeStore = defineStore('darkThemeStore', {
    state: () => ({
        themeIsDark: undefined,
    }),
    actions: {
        switchTheme(){
            if (this.themeIsDark === true){
                this.themeIsDark = false
            } else if (this.themeIsDark === false){
                this.themeIsDark = true
            }
        },
    }

})
```

buttons in default.vue which will do the toggling:

```
<button class="flex text-[#2E3440] dark:text-[#ECEFF4] px-2 py-1 rounded-md transition ease-in-out hover:duration-100 dark:hover:bg-[#4C566A] hover:bg-[#ECEFF4]" v-if="themeIsDark === true" @click="changeTheme()"><i class="material-symbols-outlined my-auto">dark_mode</i></button>

<button class="flex dark:text-[#ECEFF4] px-2 py-1 rounded-md transition ease-in-out hover:duration-100 dark:hover:bg-[#4C566A] hover:bg-[#ECEFF4]" v-else @click="changeTheme()"><i class="material-symbols-outlined my-auto">light_mode</i></button>
```

EDIT:

After making edits we are a bit closer to a solution. Below are how my files now look:

default.vue

```
<script>
    import { useDarkThemeStore } from "@/stores/darkThemeStore";
    const toggleDarkMode = useDarkThemeStore();

    export default {
    computed:{
        themeIsDark(){
            return toggleDarkMode.themeIsDark
        }
        
    },
    methods: {
        changeTheme() {
            toggleDarkMode.switchTheme();
        }

    }
};
</script>
```

darkThemeStore.js

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useDarkThemeStore = defineStore('darkThemeStore', {
    state: () => ({
        themeIsDark: typeof localStorage !== 'undefined' && localStorage.theme === 'dark'
        
    }),
    actions: {
        switchTheme(){
            if (this.themeIsDark === true){
                this.themeIsDark = false
                document.documentElement.classList.remove("dark");
                localStorage.theme = 'light'
            } else if (this.themeIsDark === false){
                this.themeIsDark = true
                document.documentElement.classList.add("dark");
                localStorage.theme = 'dark'
            }
        },
    }

})
```

I also updated the buttons to use the new computed property. I am still getting the same error but now it only flashes when I reload the page while on dark mode and the button quickly switched to the light mode icon before switching back to the correct dark mode icon:

```
chunk-3Q27KRJ5.js:97 [Vue warn]: Hydration text content mismatch in <i>:
- Client: light_mode
- Server: dark_mode 
  at <Default > 
  at <LayoutLoader key="default" name="default" hasTransition=false > 
  at <NuxtLayout> 
  at <App key=3 > 
  at <NuxtRoot>
```

Edit 2:

I was able to get rid of the warning by doing a v-show on the buttons like so:

```
<button v-show="themeIsDark" @click="changeTheme()"><i class="material-symbols-outlined my-auto">dark_mode</i></button>

<button  v-show="!themeIsDark" @click="changeTheme()"><i class="material-symbols-outlined my-auto">light_mode</i></button>
```

but the flicker is still present and when on dark mode the button flashes to the light mode button for a second

EDIT 3:

I built the project and ran yarn preview to preview the build. The flicker is still present (not nearly as bad though) and the error has gone away (I did remove v-show from the buttons since that is a hacky way of fixing the problem). I'm so puzzled as to why the erorr about hydration mismatch is present in development but not in a production build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out by using cookies.

made the script section look like this:

```js
<script setup>
    import Cookies from 'js-cookie'
    
    if (typeof document !== 'undefined'){
            
        if(Cookies.get('darkModeEnabled') === 'true'){
            document.documentElement.classList.add('dark')
        
        }else {
            document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark')            
            
        }
    }

    function toggleDarkMode(){
                if (Cookies.get('darkModeEnabled') === 'true'){
                    Cookies.remove('darkModeEnabled')
                    document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark')
                } else {
                    Cookies.set('darkModeEnabled', 'true')
                    document.documentElement.classList.add('dark')
                }
            }
    
</script>
```

and added this script to the nuxt.config.ts file in the head section:

```js
script: [{children: `
      import Cookies from './node_modules/js-cookie/dist/js.cookie.mjs'
      if (Cookies.get('darkModeEnabled') === 'true'){
        document.documentElement.classList.add('dark')

      } else {
        Cookies.remove('darkModeEnabled')
        document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark')

      }

      `, type:'module'}]
```

the error is no longer present, the buttons are showing the correct icon and the theme is toggling nicely